# How to get address for http.ListenAndServe

Tags: go

Say I start a server like so:

```
srv := http.Server{
    Addr:    ":0",
    Handler: http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")),
}
go srv.ListenAndServe()
log.Printf("Listening on ???")
```

How can I tell which port was picked? `:0` is designed to pick a random ephemeral port by the OS, but I need to know which one was picked.

**NOTE:** I would prefer *not* to create my own listener and use `srv.Listen(ln)`, since `srv.ListenAndServe()` has a good default (but unexported) listener that I want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Go 1.14.1, `net/http` no longer wraps the TCP listener!

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1abf3aa55bb8b346bb1575ac8db5022f215df65a/src/net/http/server.go#L2783), it is now:

```golang
func (srv *Server) ListenAndServe() error {
    if srv.shuttingDown() {
        return ErrServerClosed
    }
    addr := srv.Addr
    if addr == "" {
        addr = ":http"
    }
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return srv.Serve(ln)
}
```

This is due to [this commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1abf3aa55bb8b346bb1575ac8db5022f215df65a), where the "keepalive" part of the listener was moved to the standard `net` package and is now turned on by default.

**So, don't worry about it!** Just create your own listener.

---

### Example

```golang
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")
if err != nil {
    return err
}
go srv.Serve(ln)
log.Printf("Listening on %s", ln.Addr().String())
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would prefer not to create my own listener and use srv.Listen(ln), since srv.ListenAndServe() has a good default (but unexported) listener that I want to use.

Why not? ListenAndServe() is extremely simple to implement yourself. You can [read the source code](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?#L2622) for it yourself:

```
func (srv *Server) ListenAndServe() error {
    addr := srv.Addr
    if addr == "" {
        addr = ":http"
    }
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return srv.Serve(tcpKeepAliveListener{ln.(*net.TCPListener)})
}
```

The answer is that you will need to use write your own ListenAndServe() that gives you the information you want. It is much easier than you believe however. The entire thing isn't more than 20 lines (assuming you want to set keep-alives with [tcpKeepAliveListener](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?#L3111)).

Comment: My preference is just a preference, I'm aware it is not difficult to go the `srv.Listen()` route. I assume that because you avoid the problem, you also can't figure out a way to get the port number?

Comment: Correct, it is actually not possible to do that without things much much worse than creating your own listener. ListenAndServe is meant to be a convenience function. As with most such functions, the second you need something that special, you need to use a lower level function.

Comment: Note that this uses the unexported `tcpKeepAliveListener` so if you want TCP keep-alives you'll also need to [copy that source](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=51082:51123#L1967) thankfully it's only a dozen lines of trivial code but it makes it a little more annoying to do this.

Comment: New URL for that ListenAndServe function: https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=51082:51123#L2576

Answer (score 1):

You can select a free port before configuring the server address. The simpler way to get a free port is to create a listener, so you can obtain the same result following Stephen suggestion.

```
func GetFreePort() (int, error) {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":0")
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    err = ln.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return ln.Addr().(*net.TCPAddr).Port, nil
}
```

Here a complete example https://play.golang.org/p/bG4OpmQbz9s

Comment: What if the OS assigns that port to another process in the meanwhile?

Comment: In that case you get an error starting the server, so you need to test if the error happens and repeat the operation. Choose another port calling the method GetFreePort again and restart the server.